# Keypad stops working when using USB modem

Tags: windows-7

Can someone please help me with this issue. I will be working on my Laptop (Toshiba Qosimo, windows 7, 64 bits) with a Telstra USB modem, without warning the keypad justs stops working, all my work up to this point is then lost, due to having to restart the laptop & then everything works fine until it happens again. It doesn't happen consistently, but sometimes it can run for hours without a problem & then it can happen just after you turn it on. Has anybody else experienced this as well & be able to share any solutions or suggestions.

Thank you

Doug

Answer (score 0):

If this only happens when you use the modem, it might be a driver collision/problem.
Next time you plug in your USB modem, go to device manager (right click Computer->Manage and select Device Manager from the tree) and look for yellow exclamation marks.

Before I do anything drastic though, the next time your keyboard stops responding, try plugging in an external USB keyboard and see if that works.

If your modem is quite old, there could also be a case of interrupt collision with the keyboard - that can be fixed in the BIOS settings.

Good luck!